# Get Process' Name and User

Tags: qt, process

How can I get via QT, the process' name and its user name.

e.g, on windows rundll32.exe is a process with name "rundll32.exe" and its username is the user's windows account name. but svchost.exe is a process, whose username is "SYSTEM"

I need in my running process to get my process' name and its id, and the username. I could find in qt-forums the answer :/

Thanks !

Comment: you want to get it for any running process or only for your own qt process??

Comment: for any running process, but in the process i already use QT-stuff. I want to do this with Qt, so that my code stays compilable on windows and linux.

Comment: I am pretty sure there is no built-in class for this... you have to do it yourself on each platform.

Comment: so you mean use #if #else #endif ... which is i do it.

Comment: better: creat two definitions files `processreader_unix.cpp` and `processreader_win32.cpp`, use qmake to choose which file to use at make time.

Comment: my project is not able to use make :) but yes your suggestion is true and would work fine. i used #if WIN32 else ... which runs too. More over, i found a way too; but it works without Qt. Just from main i get via argument list the path of executable, so I can the process name .